# Saved audio with electron app not playing

Tags: javascript, electron

I want to save recorded voice of mine to hard disk using electron. so far I'm here: (the recording functions are tested and work fine)

in the recorder.js which is my own script I have this:

```
const Buffer = require('Buffer');
const fs = require('fs');

let blob
let audioChunks = [];
let rec;
document.head.innerHTML += '<audio id="recordedAudio" crossorigin="anonymous"></audio>';
let recordedAudio = document.getElementById('recordedAudio');
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio:true}).then(stream => {
    rec = new MediaRecorder(stream);
    rec.ondataavailable = e => {
        if(rec.state == "inactive") {
            audioChunks.push(e.data);
            blob = new Blob(audioChunks,{type:'audio/x-mpeg-3'});
            recordedAudio.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        }
    }
}).catch(e=>console.log(e));


setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('start record');
    rec.start(); 
}, 2000);

setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('stop record');
    rec.stop(); 
    setTimeout(() => {
        saveFile()
    }, 2500) 
}, 8000);

async function saveFile() {
    const buffer = Buffer.from( await blob.arrayBuffer() );
    fs.writeFile('./sources/rex3.mp3', buffer, () => console.log('audio saved!') );
}
```

I have changed my meta in index.js to this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * self blob: data: gap:; style-src * self 'unsafe-inline' blob: data: gap:; script-src * 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' blob: data: gap:; object-src * 'self' blob: data: gap:; img-src * self 'unsafe-inline' blob: data: gap:; connect-src self * 'unsafe-inline' blob: data: gap:; frame-src * self blob: data: gap:;">
```

Without any errors I can see the console log of 'audio saved!' and the mp3 file is saved to the given path './sources/rex3.mp3' corrrectly but when I play the audio nothing plays at all...

What I miss and how can I fix this?

Comment: Does `./sources/rex3.mp3` contain anything at all? Or is it empty?

Comment: The rex3.mp3 is saved correctly...